# ng-bind-html in angular bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using an angular bootstrap modal with an ng-bind-html directive in the template but the ng-clicks in the html that is being binded do not work.

```
$scope.shouldWork = function () {
  // stuff
};
$scope.html1 = '<span ng-click="shouldWork()"></span>'
var modal = $modal.open({
  $scope,
  template: '<div ng-bind-html="html1"></div>'
});
```

`shouldWork()` never gets called. Is there anyway to get this to work?

Comment: you need to compile the content after modifying the html1 variable you need to get a handle on the new content using angular.element and then use $compile to bind the scope to the new elements

Comment: That still doesn't work. I'm pretty sure this is some kind of security feature with ng-bind-html the html is being compiled but I think it purposefully removes any ng-click directives.